# Calculation involving two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two `DataFrame`

df1:

```
   mat  inv 
0  100   23  
1  101   35  
2  102  110
```

df2:

```
   mat  sale
0  100   45
1  101  100
2  102   90
```

I merged the `DataFrame` in `df`:

```
   mat  inv  sale
0  100   23   45
1  101   35  100
2  102  110   90
```

so I could create another column `days`:

```
df['days'] = df.inv / df.sale * 30
```

then I delete the column `sale`, and get this as result:

df:

```
   mat  inv  days
0  100   23   15
1  101   35   10
2  102  110   36
```

Can I create the `days`column directly in `df1` without first merging the `DataFrame`? since I don't need the column of `df2`, just the value to do the operation of `days`, and I don't really want to merge them to delete it in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also do it this way:

```
In [181]: df1['days'] = (df1.inv / df1['mat'].map(df2.set_index('mat')['sale']) * 30).astype(int)

In [182]: df1
Out[182]:
   mat  inv  days
0  100   23    15
1  101   35    10
2  102  110    36
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create the new column directly if you make sure the `mat` columns align properly:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('mat')
df2 = df2.set_index('mat')
df2['days'] = df1.inv.div(df2.sale).mul(30)

     sale     days
mat                 
100     4    15.33
101   100    10.50
102    90    36.67
```

Answer (score 0):

surely `df1['days'] = df1['inv'] / df2['sale'] * 30` works?

Comment: `df1` and `df2` doesn't have the rows in the same order, `mat` is just another column, but I need `inv` and `sale` to be from the same `mat` row

Comment: in that case just set the index to `mat` as per Stefan's answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful response, Bassem.

Comment: My answer was an answer. Period.